# Regular expressions: how to match a word from an outside of given html tah?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say that I have an HTML markup like this:

```
<p>
    <h1>Some header, which I don't want to match</h1>
    Some text - match it.
    <a href="some-file.html">Some link. Don't match neither href nor link text.<a>
    <span>Some word, which needs to be matched</span>
</p>
```

In few words, I want to match some word in whole of the content, except given html tags (and their attributes). In given example I want to exclude h1 and a tags.

Expected result after replacing 'Some' by 'Test':

```
<p>
    <h1>Some header, which I don't want to match</h1>
    Test text - match it.
    <a href="some-file.html">Some link. Don't match neither href nor link text.<a>
    <span>Test word, which needs to be matched</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Use php DOM and XPath

Comment: Yeah thanks, this is some solution, but still I would be happy to know a regex way of solving it :)

Comment: nope, completely different topic :)

Comment: @user1832207: even if you really like to shave your beard with a spoon - it's silly as soon as there is a razor blade available. But you still can continue wasting your time if you wish so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `<(a|h1)[^\>]*?>(some)[^\<]*?<\/\1>`  to match the lines containing `some` and between html tags .

And check if a line not satisfying this regex , then replace word some  (if any ) with your required replacement text.

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aT4rK4)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: "to exclude h1 and a tags"

Comment: Yes, it will exclude almost all html tags

Comment: OP doesn't want to exclude all html tags, but some

Comment: that's true. Want to choose which tags to exclude.